# Hedera, Following getting started I got errors in the first page

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I am trying to follow the first example in the documentation https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/getting-started/environment-set-up ( **JS** ), but I got this error after running the index.js

```
/home/development/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/transaction/TransactionReceipt.cjs:166
    this.serials = props.serials ?? [];
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I just used the command "node index.js" instead off "js index.js". node.js is using EcmaScript 11 that supported the double question mark for the ternary conditional.

Comment: Yes, and for completeness (and for other readers who chance upon this Q&A), ensure that you have the right version of NodeJs installed. See the "engines" section within `package.json`. Currently: https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/229fead5b73642e11827891e37dbd08720448b32/package.json#L44-L46